# Jinja's template operators (how to use function without printing it on web-site page)

Tags: python, jinja2

So, here is a part of code (line 7 is the point), where I want to know how I can pop one item out of the list on each iteration, escaping printing it on web-site page?

```
{% macro get_solution() %}
    {% set args = varargs|list %}
    {% for i in range(varargs|length) %}
        {% if args|sum|string in kwargs %}
            {{ loop.index }} - {{ kwargs[args|sum|string] }}
        {% endif %}
        {{ args.pop() }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{{ get_solution(*args, **kw) }}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting that line in a statement `{% ... %}` rather than in an expression `{{ ... }}`? https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#synopsis

Comment: Yeah, i tried, here's what it said: 
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'args'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.

Frankly, that was the first thing i tried to do, but then i realized that {% %} statements can contain only default tags such "for", "if", "set", "block" etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can pop the list element inside a statement by assigning the value to a variable, so it is not printed out in the file:

```
{% set list = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3'] %}
{{ list }}
{% set _ = list.pop() %}
{{ list }}
```

will return:

```
['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3']
['elem1', 'elem2']
```

so just replace `{{ args.pop() }}` by `{% set _ = args.pop() %}`

Comment: Thx a lot! now the code works and i finally realize how to change objects without printing them out